# Concatenate string and integer in c++ for reading multiple file in case of C++ 11 not supporting computer

Tags: c++, c++03, c++98

I would like to hear if there is a solution to this problem. my computer does not support C++ 11 so  I can not join string and integer by `std::string to_string`... instead, I used a string stream.
I want C++ part in ROOT program to read each all files by loop them and from each file read the three columns by ifstream.

```
int N= ;
for (i=1; i<=N; i++){

ending = ".dat";
name0 = "pulse_value";
ostringstream temp;
temp << i;
str = temp.str();

input = name0 + str + ending;
ifstream get(input);

for (int j=0; j<N4; j++){
      time[j]=0.;
      energy[j]=0.;
      current[j]=0.;

      get >>time[j]>>energy[j]>>current[j];
}
}
```

But it gives me :

```
Can't call basic_ifstream<char,char_traits<char> >::basic_ifstream<char,char_traits<char> >(input).
basic_ifstream<char,char_traits<char> > basic_ifstream<char,char_traits<char>>::basic_ifstream<char,char_traits<char> >(void);
```

NB: I am a recent user of C++ .
Thank  you in advance

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Problem

`ifstream get(input);` is also a C++11-ism. Before C++11, you cannot use a `std::string` as an argument to the `std::ifstream` constructor. It only accepts file names as a pointer to a null-terminated `char` array.

## Quick Fix:

```
ifstream get(input.c_str());// c_str provides a null-terminated character array
```

## Smarter Fix:

But since you have to pull out the `stringstream` for the number, you might as well go all in and use the `stringstream` to format the whole file name:

```
ostringstream temp;
temp << "pulse_value" << i << ".dat";
ifstream get(temp.str().c_str());
```